# Tableau Server Issue

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard which contains multiple reports.
All of the reports are showing the correct data-set expect one of the report.
I am getting the following error :

[image]

The field(abc) in the error screenshot is of type integer.

Please refer the environment details :

Tableau Server Version: 2019.1.2 (20191.19.0321.1733) 64-bit Windows

I am not able to understand whether it is a connection issue or field issue or data-size issue.While I was going through other thread it is observed that Driver might be one of the possible reason for this issue , so is there a way to check which Driver is installed on Tableau Server for Redshift ?

It will be great if someone could help me to understand the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved when I installed latest Redshift Driver ( from AWS Website ) over the Tableau Server.